# How to parse taggedword using stanford NLP

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

I have a list of tagged sentences stored in txt file in the following format:

```
We_PRP 've_VBP just_RB wrapped_VBN up_RP with_IN the_DT boys_NNS of_IN Block_NNP B_NNP
```

Now I want parse the sentence, I found the following code:

```
String filename = "tt.txt";
    // This option shows loading and sentence-segmenting and tokenizing
    // a file using DocumentPreprocessor.
    TreebankLanguagePack tlp = new PennTreebankLanguagePack();
    GrammaticalStructureFactory gsf = tlp.grammaticalStructureFactory();
    // You could also create a tokenizer here (as below) and pass it
    // to DocumentPreprocessor
    for (List<HasWord> sentence : new DocumentPreprocessor(filename)) {
        Tree parse = lp.apply(sentence);
        parse.pennPrint();
        System.out.println();

        GrammaticalStructure gs = gsf.newGrammaticalStructure(parse);
        Collection tdl = gs.typedDependenciesCCprocessed();
        System.out.println(tdl);
        System.out.println();
    }
```

The parse result is long, and I wondered the problem lay on this line new DocumentPreprocessor(filename) it actually retag my sentence, any way to skip the tagging step?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer in the [Parser FAQ](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/parser-faq.shtml#f), I tried and it works for me

```
// set up grammar and options as appropriate
LexicalizedParser lp = LexicalizedParser.loadModel(grammar, options);
String[] sent3 = { "It", "can", "can", "it", "." };
// Parser gets tag of second "can" wrong without help                    
String[] tag3 = { "PRP", "MD", "VB", "PRP", "." };                             
List sentence3 = new ArrayList();
for (int i = 0; i < sent3.length; i++) {
  sentence3.add(new TaggedWord(sent3[i], tag3[i]));
}
Tree parse = lp.parse(sentence3);
parse.pennPrint();
```